# regex from two files

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, bioinformatics, paste

I have two files that built of blocks of 4 lines, starting with a @. They are matching and in order. The files are too big (>10 GB) so I am putting here the first 3 blocks of each (12 lines).

1st: the R file (reference file):

```
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:3598:1051 2:N:0:NATC
CAATCTCTAAAGTTT
+
AA/A/EEEE///EEE
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:24202:1051 2:N:0:NTCG
TGAGACCGGGTGTTG
+
AAAAAAEEE///<AA
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:4381:1051 2:N:0:NCTT
GCTACTCCTAAGGCA
+
A////6/////EE//
```

2nd: the I file (index file):

```
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:3598:1051 1:N:0:NATC
NATC
+
#EEE
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:24202:1051 1:N:0:NTCG
NTCG
+
#EEE
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:4381:1051 1:N:0:NCTT
NCTT
+
#EEA
```

The output file should contain the following (for each block (4 lines)):

1. The first line exactly as in R2 (it has a space in it, it is important to keep)
2. concatenate the 4 characters (always 4 letters) of the 2nd line from the I file to the beginning of the 2nd line of the R file.
3. keep the 3rd line as the 3rd line in the R file
4. concatenate the 4th lines (any character) in the I file to the beginning of the 4th line in the R file.
5. do it to all blocks

example of an output:

```
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:3598:1051 2:N:0:NATC
NATCCAATCTCTAAAGTTT
+
#EEEAA/A/EEEE///EEE
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:24202:1051 2:N:0:NTCG
NTCGTGAGACCGGGTGTTG
+
#EEEAAAAAAEEE///<AA
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:4381:1051 2:N:0:NCTT
NCTTGCTACTCCTAAGGCA
+
#EEAA////6/////EE//
```

Thanks a lot, 
HM

Comment: Exemplary test processing question, by the way: Clear border condition, comprehensive processing description and a simplified, yet useful example with input and desired output. I wish everyone would ask that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $f1 = shift;
my $f2 = shift;

open(F1,"<",$f1) || die "couldn't open '$f1' for read: $!\n";
open(F2,"<",$f2) || die "couldn't open '$f2' for read: $!\n";

# set the input record separator (IRS) to '@'
$/='@';

# Normally the IRS is found at the END of a record, but your input
# files START with the input record separator, so we need to throw
# away the first (bogus) input record (i.e. everything from the start
# of the files to the first @ characters in them. in other words, the
# first @ characters in both files.)
my $junk = <F1>;
$junk = <F2>;

while (!eof(F1) && !eof(F2)) {
  my @record1 = split(/\n/, <F1>);
  my @record2 = split(/\n/, <F2>);

  printf "%s%s\n", $/, $record1[0];  # prepend the IRS
  printf "%s%s\n", substr($record2[1],0,4), $record1[1];
  printf "%s\n",   $record2[2];
  printf "%s%s\n", $record2[3], $record1[3];
};

close(F1);
close(F2);
```

This opens both files for read, and sets perl's `$/` input record separator variable to an `@` character.

Then, while both files haven't reached EOF, it reads a record from each file, splitting the records into arrays (using newline `\n` as the delimiter), and then outputs the merged records as specified.

Note that perl arrays start from 0, not 1 - so, e.g., `$record1[0]` is the first line of the record from file1.

Save the script to a file (e.g. `hassan.pl`), make it executable with `chmod +x hassan.pl` and run it as shown below:

Sample output:

```
$ ./hassan.pl file1.txt file2.txt  
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:3598:1051 2:N:0:NATC
NATCCAATCTCTAAAGTTT
+
#EEEAA/A/EEEE///EEE
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:24202:1051 2:N:0:NTCG
NTCGTGAGACCGGGTGTTG
+
#EEEAAAAAAEEE///<AA
@NB551168:120:HTKN2BGX5:1:11101:4381:1051 2:N:0:NCTT
NCTTGCTACTCCTAAGGCA
+
#EEAA////6/////EE//
```

(I verified with `diff` that this output matches your desired output exactly).

Answer (score 0):

I put it in other words: Except for the `+` line and the line starting with `@`, paste the `I` lines before the `R` lines.

If you see it that why, it gets really simple:

```
sed '/^[@+]/s/.*//' I|paste -d '' - R
```

- `/^[@+]/` selectes lines starting with `+` or `@`
- `s/.*//` empties those lines
- `paste -d '' - R` pasted the result (`-` for the piped input) without delimiter (`-d ''`) to the `R` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Gnu sed, you can do this:

```
$ sed -e 'R I' R | sed -ne 'p;n;n;h;n;G;s/\n//p'
```